# Navigation sprites not aligning

Tags: html, css, navigation, sprite

Calling on your help again guys..

Not sure what's happening here, my navigation rollovers are not aligning correctly, I've checked my measurements and from what I see it isn't that. I'm aligning the navigation to the centre of the page using Margin:0 auto; I'm wondering if this is the problem?

I've created a Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ca9rv/ to make sense of what I'm rambling about (not sure why theres a blue line at the bottom - this doesn't show when viewing my html page locally).

```
<ul id="navigation">
    <li id="home"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li id="promise"><a href="Our Promise">Our Promise</a></li>
    <li id="restaurants"><a href="Our Restaurants">Resume</a></li>
    <li id="contact"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>

#navigation {
    background:url(http://img33.imageshack.us/img33/7388/navigationq.png) no-repeat;
    width: 940px;
    height: 50px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    margin-bottom:20px;
}

#navigation li, #navigation a {
    height: 50px;
    display: block;
}

#navigation li {
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
    display: inline;
    text-indent: -9999em;
}

#home { width: 103px; }
#promise { width: 176px; }
#restaurants { width: 206px; }
#contact { width: 151px; }

#home a:hover { background:url("http://img33.imageshack.us/img33/7388/navigationq.png") 0px -50px no-repeat; }
#promise a:hover { background:url("http://img33.imageshack.us/img33/7388/navigationq.png") -103px -50px no-repeat; }
#restaurants a:hover { background:url("http://img33.imageshack.us/img33/7388/navigationq.png") -277px -50px no-repeat; }
#contact a:hover { background:url("http://img33.imageshack.us/img33/7388/navigationq.png") -482px -50px no-repeat; }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Change your** `position value` and `width`

**as like this**

```
#home { width: 88px; }
#promise { width: 147px; }
#restaurants { width: 176px; }
#contact { width: 128px; }

#home a:hover { background:url("http://img33.imageshack.us/img33/7388/navigationq.png") 0px -42px no-repeat; }
#promise a:hover { background:url("http://img33.imageshack.us/img33/7388/navigationq.png") -91px -42px no-repeat; }
#restaurants a:hover { background:url("http://img33.imageshack.us/img33/7388/navigationq.png") -236px -42px no-repeat; }
#contact a:hover { background:url("http://img33.imageshack.us/img33/7388/navigationq.png") -411px -42px no-repeat; }
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ca9rv/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

First of i think you are doing it all wrong.
1. Stop using background image, because you want it to scale.
2. Just a quick look at the CSS you have all the width wrong. Add a border to all the elements and you will se whats is happening.
3. You have the blue border there because the height on the menu is higher then the background-image.

Comment: Thanks Joacim, I see where you're coming from - for some reason image shack resized my image and I had not noticed until a few moments ago. Please see my comment above to Rohit. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

[**Jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/bhushan004/DcBeq/)

```
<style>

#navigation {
    background:url(http://img33.imageshack.us/img33/7388/navigationq.png) no-repeat;
    width: 940px;
    height: 42px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    margin-bottom:20px;
}

#navigation li, #navigation a {
    height: 50px;
    display: block;
}

#navigation li {
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
    display: inline;
    text-indent: -9999em;
}

#home { width: 87px; }
#promise { width: 149px; }
#restaurants { width: 175px; }
#contact { width: 130px; }

#home a:hover { background:url("http://img33.imageshack.us/img33/7388/navigationq.png") 0px -42px no-repeat; }
#promise a:hover { background:url("http://img33.imageshack.us/img33/7388/navigationq.png") -91px -42px no-repeat; }
#restaurants a:hover { background:url("http://img33.imageshack.us/img33/7388/navigationq.png") -82px -42px no-repeat; }
#contact a:hover { background:url("http://img33.imageshack.us/img33/7388/navigationq.png") -409px -42px no-repeat; }
</style>
<ul id="navigation">
    <li id="home"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li id="promise"><a href="Our Promise">Our Promise</a></li>
    <li id="restaurants"><a href="Our Restaurants">Resume</a></li>
    <li id="contact"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Hi Bhushan, many thanks for taking the time to look at this. Unfortuanely imageshack resized the image - I'm 99% sure my positionings are correct for when the image is actual size. Not sure but I'm wondering if sprites are really needed for this. Would css only be a cleaner solution?

Comment: yeah! right you must go with css, since there are no gradients involved.